# How to split a TokenStream?

Tags: rust

I'm writing an attribute macro and need to implement custom parsing for the attributes passed into the macro.

Given the `TokenStream` built from the source `(1,1), 2`, how can I split this into two `TokenStream`s: `(1,1)` & `2`?

Comment: You could use `to_string()` and afterwards `split`, but you should show us some more code of what you have done so far.